# How to disallow line breaks in CKEditor widget editables?

Tags: ckeditor

For a client I made a quote-widget and one of the editable fields is the name. It is declared like this:

```
editor.widgets.add('quote', {
  editables: {
    name: {
      selector: '.quote__name',
      allowedContent: ' '
    },
```

And it the template it looks like this:

```
'<strong class="quote__name">Ola Nordmann</strong>' +
```

I'm not sure if having 1 space inside allowedContent is a hack, but it seems to disallow all content which is what I want. Passing an empty string seems to cause it to be ignored. I only want the client to be able to change the name inside the strong tag and not be able to mess up any formatting, but at the moment they're able to press "Enter" inside the strong tag and add line breaks. I've tried everything, but there doesn't seem to be any way for me to disallow line breaks. The worst part is that if they add a line break inside the strong tag and save the node (This is Drupal) if they later come back and edit the node the line break has moved outside the strong tag and because this is a widget they can only edit what's inside the editables so there's no way for them to remove the line break without going into html source mode and manually removing it or deleting the widget and inserting it again.

So is there a way to completely disallow line breaks inside a widget editable?

Answer (score 1):

This code will prevent line breaks when editable is focused.

```
editable.on('focus', function(){
    editor.on('key', disableEnterKey);
})

editable.on('blur', function(){
    editor.removeListener('key', disableEnterKey);
});

function disableEnterKey(e){
    if(e.data.keyCode === 13) {
        e.cancel();
    }
}
```